# HDF5.dll version conflict between Matlab MCR v9.1 and my application

Tags: c#, matlab, dll, pinvoke, hdf5

MyApp is a C# .NET v4.5.2 WPF app. MyAssembly is a Matlab .NET assembly I created containing MyClass. MyAssembly requires MCR v9.1. MyApp performs various tasks; when one requires Matlab and it tries to instantiate MyClass then a popup window displays:

> The procedure entry point H5Rdereference could not be located in dynamic link library C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v91\bin\win64\libmat.dll.

MyApp contains a version of hdf5.dll (obtained from Nuget package HDF.PInvoke v1.10.1), and I discovered that MCR 9.1 also contains a (different) version of hdf5.dll in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v91\bin\win64. When I replaced MyApp's version of that dll with MCR 9.1's version, MyApp is able to instantiate MyClass, but then MyApp is no longer able to perform its HDF5 tasks; calls to H5.open() throw:

> Unable to load DLL 'hdf5.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

MyClass doesn't require HDF5, so why is the MCR loading its copy of that DLL?
How do I get around this conflict?

Update 1: I moved all of MyApp's non-Matlab-related use of HDF5 into a separate app domain, but the problem persists. It is as if HDF5.dll is getting loaded into the primary app domain even though the code that loads it is executing in a separate app domain.

Comment: Matlab only allows one instance of the license to be used at a time.  I think you are checking out to instances of the license.

Comment: HDF5 is a core component of MATLAB, it's used to read and write MAT-files (MATLAB's own data file format). Probably the simplest solutions are to either downgrade your version of hdf5.dll to match MATLAB's (not just replace the DLL, but also the corresponding header files), or replace MyApp's use of HDF5 with MATLAB functionalty. I don't know enough about Windows to know if it's possible to keep these two hdf5.dll libraries separate.

Comment: @jdweng: The MRC does not require or use MATLAB licenses.

Comment: MCR still only allows once instance.

Comment: @jdweng If that is true, it's a new thing. This has not been the case when I used the MATLAB Compiler ~10 years ago. You need a license to build the application/library. Once deployed, there are no restrictions on the use of the application/library.

Comment: I don't think this is a licensing issue. Per https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-dotnet-application-with-matlab-code.html the target system does not require any licenses.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, MyApp doesn't consume hdf5.dll directly, only indirectly via the PInvoke library. I only did the substitution described above to demonstrate that Matlab was the instigator. Thanks to your comment, I now know why it has to load its copy of HDF5.dll. I won't be able to use Matlab to meet all of MyApp's HDF5 needs, so I guess I need to figure out how to have MyApp load its own copy, maybe in an app domain.

Comment: The matlab library has a build in lock that only allows one process to call a library method at a time.

Comment: @jdweng I see. MyApp only calls the methods found in MyClass from one place. That's not the issue.

Comment: The exception says the module cannot be found, not the dll.  Matlab before 2015 often changed names and eliminate obsolete methods.  So maybe you are calling a method that isn't in the runtime library you are using.  Or calling a toolbox that you do not have.

Comment: @jdweng Those are reasonable considerations. Depending on which of the following tasks is executed first, the other task will fail when executed:
{Task: Using MyClass | Task: Using HDF5.PInvoke} 
Since those two task categories each require their own version of HDF5.dll, my only solution seems to be to load both versions, which I believe is only possible using App Domains.

Comment: I would compile your code with the same version of matlab that hdf5 used so you do not need two different versions of matlab.   You can have two different version of matlab installed at same time.

Comment: @jdweng That is a good idea, too. MyApp is actually a framework that built on by many apps, some of which use Matlab .NET assemblies; the MCR version required by these apps varies. The framework is where the non-Matlab HDF5 services are implemented, so I now believe it is best that I get out of the way of the app developers by moving my HDF5 code into an AppDomain so they can be free to use whichever MCR makes sense for their requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDF5.dll is a native DLL and thus not bound by AppDomain boundaries.